# Google App Script + Google Sheet - Fetch URL from cell (which links to separate sheet) and pull in sheet tab from linked sheet

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I've been working/researching this for a few days and get close, but need to add an element of automation, my current scripts are not suitable for the end goal.

**I need to:**

- Grab a URL from a cell on my primary "generator" sheet.
- The URL points to a completely separate Google Sheet.
- I need to grab a specific named sheet tab, from the externally linked Google Sheet, and bring it into my master doc, as a new sheet tab.
- The source cell with the URL, may be replaced with a new link, hence the automation required. I do not want to have multiple scripts with hard-coded sheet IDs or URLs.
- The URL link may change, but each external sheet will have a tab with the same name, so that remains consistent.

It seems if I store the URL cell (B28 in this case contains the URL) as a variable in the script, it no longer becomes readable. EG:

```
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calc Generator");
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_SHEET.getRange("B28");
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE.getValues();
```

Afterwards my script can no longer grab the URL. Any help would be appreciated, I'm a little snow blind at this point!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `Afterwards my script can no longer grab the URL.`. Can you explain about the detail of it? 2. If `Afterwards my script can no longer grab the URL.` is your issue and you want to resolve it, what is `I need to:`? Are we required to prepare the script achieving all of `I need to:`?

Comment: Hi! No: I have the rest of the script ready, it was just an issue resolving the URL as a variable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE.getValues();
```

to this

```
var SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE.getValue();
```

In other words remove the s at the end.  If you don't then the value you need becomes `SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE[0][0]`  Even though it's just one cell it's still a two dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but when I go to grab a specific sheet tab from the linked sheet I get this error:

"Cannot find function getSheetByName in object"

based on:

var sourceSheet = SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE;
var source_sheet = sourceSheet.getSheetByName("Info Calculations");

I assume that getSheetByName is for SpreadsheetApp only.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured this out. It will fetch a URL of an external sheet, from a cell on a specific sheet of your own, and pull in the external sheet to yours and create a new tab copy of it.

As Cooper said, setting getValue helped, but then I can use openByURL and point to my link variable to grab it, this allows grabbing of specific external sheet tabs.

Thank you for the help!

```
    function copySheettest()
{
  //  
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("[MASTER] Calc Generator");
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_SHEET.getRange("B28");
  var SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE = SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE.getValue();
  Logger.log(SPREADSHEET_URL_REFERENCE_SOURCE_RANGE);



  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE);
  var source_sheet = sourceSheet.getSheetByName("Info Calculations");
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("target_sheet");
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("A1:AA69");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A1:AA69");
  //
  var values = source_range.getValues();
  var bGcolors = source_range.getBackgrounds();
  var colors = source_range.getFontColors();
  var fontSizes = source_range.getFontSizes();
  // make use of autocomplete to find other methods...
  target_range.setValues(values);
  target_range.setBackgrounds(bGcolors);
  target_range.setFontColors(colors);
  target_range.setFontSizes(fontSizes);
}
```

Comment: You  could use getValues() if you wish but then this line `var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE);` would need to be like this `var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL_VALUE[0][0]);`